# How to extract a nested nullable Avro Schema

Tags: avro

The complete schema is the following:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "envelope",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "before",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "row",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "username",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "name": "timestamp",
              "type": "long"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "after",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "row"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I wanted to programmatically extract the following sub-schema:

```
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "row",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "username",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "name": "timestamp",
              "type": "long"
            }
          ]
        }
```

As you see, field "before" is nullable. I can extract it's schema by doing:

```
schema.getField("before").schema()
```

But the schema is not a record as it contains NULL at the beginning(UNION type) and I can't go inside to fetch schema of "row".

```
["null",{"type":"record","name":"row","fields":[{"name":"username","type":"string"},{"name":"tweet","type":"string"},{"name":"timestamp","type":"long"}]}]
```

I want to fetch the sub-schema because I want to create GenericRecord out of it. Basically I want to create two GenericRecords "before" and "after" and add them to the main GenericRecord created from full schema.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Good news, if you have a union schema, you *can* go inside to fetch the list of possible options:

```
Schema unionSchema = schema.getField("before").schema();
List<Schema> unionSchemaContains = unionSchema.getTypes();
```

At that point, you can look inside the list to find the one that corresponds to the Type.RECORD.

Comment: And how do you look inside and find the correct schema?

Comment: `Schema myRecord = unionSchemaContains.get(1)` in this case.